# keytool is not generating md5 hash for debug.store

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

I am using the following command in cmd to generate md5 hash for my app using google maps

The command runs and no error is shown but md5 hash is not displayed in cmd:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey 
        -keystore < C:\Users\najeebullah\.android\debug.keystore>.keystore 
        -storepass android -keypass android
```

earlier i generated api key for md5 hash regarding the following command

```
keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

I got the api key from here, but my mapview display grey tiles only and not the map, so i thought that i may need to use api key for *androiddebugkey*.

Thanks in advance for any solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JDK 7 you will need to add the `-v` option to keytool to get the MD5.  By default in JDK 7 it only gives the SHA.

Comment: i tried this: keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey 
        -keystore < C:\Users\najeebullah\.android\debug.keystore>.keystore 
        -storepass android -keypass android   but found the same result. No md5 is provided in result

Comment: could you provide the output in your original question? or is there no output at all?

Comment: Done bro, got the hash, now i m gonna generate key for this, thanks alot willtate :)